# SQL pivot transform

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to use a query to return columns transformed from row from table `FloatNAR800` with pivot I have this code but doesn't work for me. Any idea ?

```
declare @nume_coloane as nvarchar(max),
        @dynamic_pivot_query as nvarchar(max)

set @nume_coloane = STUFF ((select ',' + QUOTENAME(TagIndex) 
                            from (select distinct TagIndex from FloatN2_NAR800) sub
                            order by TagIndex 
                            for xml path(''), type ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')

set @dynamic_pivot_query = 'select DateAndTime,' + @nume_coloane + 
                           'from
                                (select DateAndTime, TagIndex, Val 
                                 from FloatN2_NAR800) x
                            pivot'
```

When I want to create this query an error appears :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

but I don't know what I do wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing code... The pivot statement dos not end with the Pivot key word.

```
You code then... 
    PIVOT
        (
            <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
        FOR 
        [<column that contains the values that will become column headers>] 
            IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
            ... [last pivoted column])
        ) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```

Take a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

I would advise you to get the Pivot working first, then make it into a dynamic sql.